# Is there a standard functional name for this function?

Tags: node.js, functional-programming

I'm sure this function is likely common ( or possibly achievable other ways ) but I'm not sure of what it'd be called.   I'm thinking of a sliding window of a certain size :-

```
let slidingMap  = (arr,size, f) => {
  r = []
  arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
    let b = acc.concat(n);
    if(b.length > size)    {
      b.shift();
    }
    if(b.length == size) {
      r.push(f(b))
    }
    return b;
  },[])
  return r;
}
```

so given `slidingMap([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2, b => b)`

you'd get `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]`

and `slidingMap([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3, b => b)`

you'd get `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 4, 5 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]`

or for calculating differences  :-

`slidingMap([1,2,3,7,5,6],2, b => b.reduceRight((a, n) => a? a-n : n))`

you'd get [ 1, 1, 4, -2, 1 ]

or moving average :-

`slidingMap([1,2,3,7,5,6],3, b => b.reduce((a, n) => a+n,0)/b.length)`

you'd get `[ 2, 4, 5, 6 ]`

so, is there a commonly implemented function(s) that achieves this?

**Update**

Probablly better implemented as

```
let sliding  = (arr,size) => {
  r = []
  arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
    let b = acc.concat(n);
    if(b.length > size)    {
      b.shift();
    }
    if(b.length == size) {
      r.push(b)
    }
    return b;
  },[])
  return r;
}
```

then just use map

```
 sliding([1,2,3,4,5],2).map(somefunc);
```

**Or perhaps using zip and skip** ( using lodash in this case )

```
let sliding = (arr, size) =>  
   _.zip(..._.range(size).map(i => arr.slice(i)))
   .filter(a => !a.some(v => v == undefined))
```

only trick here is the zip will insert undefined when it has no match so they need to be filtered out.

Comment: That looks like the [`bufferCount`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount) operator in RxJS.

Comment: yes, @cartant ,  that's a superset of this, but outside of rxjs, not sure if it has a more common name, or people build it for themselves as they need it?

Comment: I'm not aware of neither a standard name for this, nor any standard library implementation. By the way, I assume you are not asking for an implementation, but if you do want to do this, a generator-based approach seems promising. In terms of the design, however, I would separate out the sliding window itself and the function applied to each window.

Comment: @torazaburo you're right, should just be sliding and then you can just use map ( or whatever )

Comment: Btw, it is generally implemented as `zip` + `skip`

Comment: @zerkms  added the zip solution, needs the backing of a functional library and depends on the zip implementation.